# Requisição Ajax para Controller Spring

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com back-end em Spring (Spring Boot) e front-end com HTML, CSS(BootStrap) e JavaScript(JQuery).

Estou com problema em montar uma requisição ajax.

Segue o código do Controller Spring:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/visualizarResumo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public @ResponseBody ResumoNFe visualizarResumo(@RequestParam Long empresaId, @RequestParam Long nsu) {
       System.out.println(empresaId);
       System.out.println(nsu);
       return resumoNFeService.buscaPorId(new ResumoPK(empresaId, nsu));
    }
```

E a requisição:

```
$('button[name=visualizarResumo]').click(function(e) { 
var buttonVisualizarResumo = $(this);
var nsu = buttonVisualizarResumo.attr('data-nsu');
var empresaId = buttonVisualizarResumo.attr('data-empresa');
console.log(nsu);
console.log(empresaId);

$.ajax({
     url: '/edocs/mde/visualizarResumo',
     method: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: JSON.stringify({empresaId:empresaId, nsu:nsu}),
     dataType : 'json',
     error: onErrorVisualizarResumo,
     success: onSuccessVisualizarResumo
});

function onErrorVisualizarResumo() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

function onSuccessVisualizarResumo() {
    console.log("sucesso");
}
```

});

Olhando nas ferramentas do Chrome, o Request Payload é montado certo com o empresaId e nsu. Contudo é me retornado uma bad request (400)

exception
:
"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException"

message
:
"Required Long parameter 'empresaId' is not present"

Comment: Experimente trocar parâmetro por body, dessa forma: `visualizarResumo(@RequestBody String payload)`

Comment: Certo, agora a requisição funcionou, mas não teria como ela chegar já convertida nas duas variáveis ao invés de vir o payload?

Comment: Dessa forma não, ou você poderia mudar de POST para GET e passar como parâmetro de URL.

Comment: Obrigado @LucasCosta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que os parâmetros estão como RequestParam, mas os valores estão indo no corpo da requisição.

Tanto que se vc der um post na uri "http://localhost:8080/visualizarResumo?empresaId=10&nsu=10" você os receberá na controller.

Se seu interesse é enviar realmente no corpo da requisição, você pode fazer assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/visualizarResumo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public @ResponseBody String visualizarResumo(@RequestBody(required = true) Map<String,Object> corpo) {
    System.out.println(corpo);
    return String.format("%7d %7d", corpo.get("empresaId"), corpo.get("nsu"));
}
```

Mas se sua requisição não altera nenhum estado no servidor, você pode fazer um GET mesmo. Não sei da sua regra de negócio, mas me parece que ficaria mais educado.

Também diria pra repassar para uma outra camada a requisição, ficando a cabo da controller cuidar de receber a requisição, repassar pra outra camada, pegar o retorno e devolver.

Qualquer dúvida, é só perguntar!

Comment: Entendi onde eu estava errando e consegui resolver o problema da requisição. Obrigado. Poderia me explicar melhor o que quis dizer em repassar a requisição para outra camada pegar o retorno e devolver. Já não é o que eu estou fazendo chamando "return resumoNFeService.buscaPorId(new ResumoPK(empresaId, nsu));", no caso esta indo para uma camada de serviço.

Comment: Oi cara. Sua dúvida é bem interessante nesse sentido, pois ela é bem conceitual e eu noto que não é algo tão trivial da galera pegar.
Pensa o seguinte, a função do controller deve ser só de receber e repassar a informação, e talvez fazer a tomada de decisão com o que volta.
Por exemplo, se cuspir uma exception, então deve retornar um ResponseEntity com HttpStatus 500. 
Essa é a obrigação do controller, e só essa. 
Fazer acesso à banco é da dao. 
Talvez colocar uma camada de façade no meio resolva. 
Dá uma olhada nessa pattern(façade), deve te guiar um pouco mais. Qlq coisa, só avisar.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. Já tinha visto esse pattern, mas não cheguei a usar. Vou estudar ele de novo e aplicar no meu caso pra ver como fica. Valeu.